# What is added to an executable when linking with a shared library?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

If I want to create a C++ program that links with a static library, then the final executable will contain both the code from my program, and the code from the library (I think...!). But I'm not entirely sure as to what happens when I link with a shared library.

Suppose I link with a library called `libfoo.so`, by specifying in my `CMakeLists.txt` file the line `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} foo)`. I'm assuming that the final executable will contain some information about this library, but not the full code. What is this other information? And furthermore, does the library have to be called exactly `libfoo.so` on the user's system?

Comment: Note: The C++ standard generally does not support dynamic libraries. About the closest to explicit support you get is the statement about initialization of namespace scope variables possibly being delayed to after the first statement of `main`. The wording in the standard is just as misleading, I guess the only reasonable interpretation is "after the start of the first statement of `main`".

Comment: The executable has a header that contains information in different sections. If you are interested in exploring the headers, you may use the linux utility `readelf` to read the headers on an elf executable. In particular, you will need `-d` and `-s` switches to display Dynamic Section and Symbol Table respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you link to a dynamic library, the linker will add a `NEEDED` entry in the dynamic section of the program. Then the dynamic loader will use these to locate the library and use the library to solve any undefined dynamic symbol.

Note that there is no connection between the undefined dynamic symbols and the dynamic libraries where they are expected to be found. Sometimes they are found in another library and interesting things may happen.

The particular name stored in the `NEEDED` entry depends on whether the library has a `SONAME` entry in its dynamic section:

- If there is a `SONAME`, then its contents will be copied to the `NEEDED` of the program
- If there is no `SONAME`, the the file name of the library as used in the linker command will be stored.

You can check the contents of the dynamic section of a library or program with:

```
$ objdump -p program
```

---

How is this used in practice? Well, most (all?) linux distributions use the following scheme, with the system libraries (take `libfoo.so`):

- The library is installed as `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1.2` or whatever version it is.
- The are symbolic links to that library named `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1` and `/usr/lib/libfoo.so`.
- The `SONAME` of the library is `libfoo.so.1`.
- The path `/usr/lib` is set as as dynamic library path.

That way, when you link with `-lfoo` it will find the symlink `libfoo.so`, but will record the `SONAME` as `libfoo.so.1`. And when the program is run it will find the other symlink and load the library.

This trick is used so that you can install an ABI compatible, improved `libfoo.so.1.3` and an ABI incompatible newer `libfoo.so.2.1`, and old program will load the old library while new compilations will use the new library.

Also note that the environment variables `LD_PRELOAD`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and others affect the runtime behaviour. For more details, you can read `man ld.so`